# How to recover corrupted c drive in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

I have been troubled by this problem for month. Once the OS starts, or several minutes after its starting, disk C will become unavailable and I can no longer do any read or write operation in C disk, which means most applications will fail to work normally. For example if I want to create a new txt file on the desktop, a notice window like this will pop up:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from creating the file. If you continue to 
>   receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.              Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Worse thing is that I can't even copy words or files since the clipboard does not work anymore, nor install any software. Plus the error code may vary by situations...

One way to solve this problem temporarily is to clean up the system garbage using some system cleaners. But this could only make disk C works for serveral minutes then I have to clean up the system again. Sometimes cleaning the garbages does not work at all, but sometimes it does work even if the cleaner says no garbage is cleaned. I guess there must exist some files that limit my authority to operate the file in C, but how can I delete them permanently?

Comment: I would use software outside of Windows to duplicate the data on the hdd and create an image then mount that image after I replaced the hdd.

Comment: backup your files using a Linux LiveCD http://www.livecdlist.com/ before you try to fix hd or recover the OS. Use a Live CD, and move your files to an external hd. The drive could be failing, or you might lose data if you get a head of yourself. Backup first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chkdsk /r /f` command and `sfc /scannow` command in windows command shell with elevated privilege. if this does not worked then you can try [ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) in [Knoppix live cd](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html). If all failed then you can delete the file with knoppix live cd.